# How to extract data from all urls, not just the first

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This script is generating a csv with the data from only one of the urls fed into it.  There are meant to be 98 sets of results, however the `for` loop isn't getting past the first url.

I've been working on this for 12hrs+ today, what am I missing in order get the correct results?

import requests
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv

```
#Read csv
csvfile = open("gyms4.csv")
csvfilelist = csvfile.read()

def get_page_data(urls):
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url.strip())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        yield soup    # N.B. use yield instead of return

print r.text

with open("gyms4.csv") as url_file:
    for page in get_page_data(url_file):
        name = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_TITLE"}).text
        address = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_map_location"}).text
        phoneNum = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_phoneNum"}).text
        email = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_EMAIL"}).text

        th = pages.find('b',text="Category")
        td = th.findNext()
        for link in td.findAll('a',href=True):
            match = re.search(r'http://(\w+).(\w+).(\w+)', link.text)
            if match:
                web_address = link.text

gyms = [name,address,phoneNum,email,web_address]
gyms.append(gyms)

#Saving specific listing data to csv
with open ("xgyms.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in gyms:
        writer.writerow([row])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 for-loops in your code and do not specifiy which one causes problem. I assume it is the one in `get_page_date()` function.

You leave the looop exactly in the first run with the `return` assignemt. That is why you never get to the second url.

There are at least two possible solutions:

1. Append every parsed line of url to a list and return that list.
2. Move you processing code in the loops and append the parsed data to `gyms` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex.S said, `get_page_data()` returns on the first iteration, hence subsequent URLs are never accessed. Furthermore, the code that extracts data from the page needs to be executed for each page downloaded, so it needs to be in a loop too. You could turn `get_page_data()` into a generator and then iterate over the pages like this:

```
def get_page_data(urls):
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url.strip())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        yield soup    # N.B. use yield instead of return

with open("gyms4.csv") as url_file:
    for page in get_page_data(url_file):
        name = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_TITLE"}).text
        address = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_map_location"}).text
        phoneNum = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_phoneNum"}).text
        email = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_EMAIL"}).text
        # etc. etc.
```

You can write the data to the CSV file as each page is downloaded and processed, or you can accumulate the data into a list and write it in one for with `csv.writer.writerows()`.

Also you should pass the URL list to `get_page_data()` rather than accessing it from a global variable.

Comment: working over this now.  It's coming up saying `"urls"` isn't defined

Comment: @McLeodx: oh that's a bit of a typo. You _should_ pass a sequence, e.g. a list ot other iterable, of URLs to `get_page_data()` rather than reference a global variable from within the function. I've updated the answer to correct it. It now passes the open file which is an iterable.

Comment: I've got to admit, I'm confused now.  I'm getting errors about 'Nonetype' object not having an attribute of 'text'.  Also, I thought that the file had to be opened before the BeatifulSoup code?!
I'm clearly missing something

Comment: `r.text` is evaluating to `None` which means that `requests.get()` is not downloading the page. You need to look at why that is. Try printing out the url before downloading, and printing `r.text` after.

Comment: When I print out `csvfilelist` I get the list of urls, but printing out `r.text` shows `NameError: name 'r' is not defined`, and printing `get_page_data` shows `TypeError: get_page_data() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`..

I'm going to change the code I've got above for the current code I'm using now